# How to get notification unique id in api level <11 android

Tags: android, notifications

i know we can get bundle from Notification.Builder. and Notification.Builder works in Api Level 11.

is there a way to get bundle or notification unique id when the user clicks notification in Api Level 10, 8 or lower.

or is there a way get the api level and use Notification if api level lower than 11 or use Notification.Builder if api level upper than 10.

do i need to make different apk's for api level 11 and for api level 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i know we can get bundle from Notification.Builder

`Notification.Builder` has no methods that involve a `Bundle`, according to its [JavaDocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html).

> and Notification.Builder works in Api Level 11.

[`NotificationCompat.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html), from the Android Support package, works back to API Level 4.

> is there a way to get bundle or notification unique id when the user clicks notification in Api Level 10, 8 or lower.

Put the "notification unique id" in an extra on the `PendingIntent` that you use with the `Notification`.

> or is there a way get the api level

`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`

> if api level lower than 11 or use Notification.Builder if api level upper than 10.

Or, use `NotificationCompat.Builder`.

> do i need to make different apk's for api level 11 and for api level 8

Not usually.